# Migrating custom module to Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, database, custom-module

I have a Joomla 3.x module which calls the category name from the database and then shows this in the module position.

It does this with:

```
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $id = JRequest::getString('id'); 
    $view = JRequest::getString('view'); 

    if ($view == 'category') {
        $sql = "SELECT title FROM #__categories WHERE #__categories.id = $id";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT #__categories.title FROM #__content, #__categories WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = $id";
    }

    $db->setQuery($sql); 
    $category = $db->loadResult(); 
    echo '<h1>' . $category . '</h1>';
```

This works in Joomla 3, but in Joomla 4 I'm getting an error:

```
Attempted to load class "JRequest" from the global namespace.
```

What's the best way to get this working in Joomla 4?

Comment: I'd like to recommend that you not use the old-skool comma-JOIN syntax -- it is very easy for a developer to overlook this syntax.  In Joomla4, it would be a good idea to consistently implement `bind()` calls with every query that uses variables for values.  When not joining tables, you don't need to bloat your SQL adding the table name before every column.

Answer (score 4):

Lodder's answer is fully valid, however he did not want to waste time to reformulate the query part of this old script in the question. As a morning drill during my coffee time I corrected that part too:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory; 

// get the Input object if $this->input is not avail
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input; 

// $db = Factory::getDbo();
$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');

$id = $input->get('id', '', 'string');
$view = $input->get('view', '', 'string');    
    
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

if ($view == 'category') {

    $query->select('title')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = :id')
        ->bind(':id', $id);

} else {
    
    $query->select('b.title')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
        ->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__categories', 'b') . ' ON a.catid = b.id')
        ->where($db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = :id')
        ->bind(':id', $id);
}

$db->setQuery($query);
$category = $db->loadResult(); 
echo '<h1>' . $category . '</h1>';
```

Answer (score 3):

`JRequest` was deprecated in Joomla 2.5 (I think), so you can now use `JInput`, like so:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$db = Factory::getDbo();
$input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$id = $input->get('id');
$view = input->get('view');
```

You'll definitely want to update your database query, using more modern methods: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

**If** I'm not mistaken, you're currently prone to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

`$input = $app->input;` is deprecated too. You should use in Joomla 4 `$input = $app->getInput();` instead.

Also you can load database form DI container by this code:

```
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseInterface;
$db = Factory::getContainer()->get(DatabaseInterface::class);
```

Comment: `$app->input` is going to be deprecated in Joomla 5, same with the database calls. The question is about refactoring an old script for Joomla4. Your post is not answering the original question but more like a comment on other answers.

Comment: Joomla 5 will come in october 2023. Do you want to update your code again six months later? Why, if you can write immediately using new methods.

Comment: You can of course if you prepare your extension for Jooma 5 already. At Joomla 6 we will get to the Facade system most probably. I am not convinced that they will keep calling the database via containers for a long time in J.5 though…

Comment: We will arrive back to `getDb()`…

Comment: @Zollie is it the official position of production department about Facade? Where we can get more information?

Comment: @DmitrijsRekuns - no, it is not at all official, I just mentioned it as an example of how fast the architecture is moving/changing in Joomla or the direction toward something. It is my estimation only that Facade is going to be the next station as I see the direction of development. So it is only my bet, nothing else.

Comment: Btw. You can also use $input = new Input()